# how to remove the last li::after for first line in specific width of an div

Tags: html, css

```css
.footer-links{             
    width: 600px;    
    margin: 0 auto;             
    background-color: #efefef;         
}
.footer-links li {             
    display: inline-block;             
    padding: 2px 0 6px 20px;         
}         
.footer-links li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;         
}         
a{             
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;             
  line-height: 25px; 
}         
a:hover{
  color: #c56;         
}         
.footer-links li::after {             
  color:#c95413;             
  content: "/";             
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.footer-links li:last-child::after {            
 display: none;         
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Here is my HTML how it looks like

```
    <div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

here is my CSS looks like

```
.footer-links{             
    width: 600px;    
    margin: 0 auto;             
    background-color: #efefef;         
}
.footer-links li {             
    display: inline-block;             
    padding: 2px 0 6px 20px;         
}         
.footer-links li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;         
}         
a{             
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;             
  line-height: 25px; 
}         
a:hover{
  color: #c56;         
}         
.footer-links li::after {             
  color:#c95413;             
  content: "/";             
  margin-left: 18px;
}
.footer-links li:last-child::after {            
 display: none;         
}
```

I want to remove these thing which is marked in the red color. Link is dynamically added so we can't say which will be the last `li` in the first line and which will 'li' will wrap to next line. how can we handle this?

https://jsfiddle.net/mrganeshraj/q99dkLk2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code of jquery. Add class to li and remove divider with css.

```
var linkHgt = $('li').height();
$('li').each(function(){  
  if($(this).position().top > linkHgt){    
    $(this).css('padding-left','0');
    $(this).prev('li').addClass('break');
    return false;
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

@ganeshraj Is this the way you need?

```css
.footer-links{             
    width: 600px;    
    margin: 0 auto;             
    background-color: #efefef;         
}
.footer-links li {             
    display: inline-block;             
    padding: 2px 0 6px 20px;         
}         
.footer-links li:first-child {
    padding-left: 0;         
}         
a{             
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;             
  line-height: 25px; 
}         
a:hover{
  color: #c56;         
}         
/*.footer-links li::after {             
  color:#c95413;             
  content: "/";             
  margin-left: 18px;
}*/
.footer-links li:last-child::after {            
 display: none;         
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy something</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem Partners</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>          
        <li><a href="#">Buy products</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ecosystem products</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```